# Divide a matrix rowwise by its own sum

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I have this matrix

```
K=
0 0 1
0 2 1
0 1 1

L= 
1
3
2
```

where `L` is the sum of each row of `K`

I need to make a new matrix through dividing each row of `K` by its sum, for example from 2nd row `[0 2 1]` the output that I should get is `[0 2/3 1/3]` or `[0 0.67 0.33]`:

```
Output=
0   0     1
0   0.67  0,33
0   0.5   0.5
```

I'm trying to use this code, but got only zeros:

```
for i=1:3;
    j=1:3;
    if K(i,j)>0
        K(i,j)=(K(i,j))/L(i)
    else
        K(i,j)=0
    end
end
```

How can I divide each row of `K` by its own sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
K=[0 0 1; 0 2 1; 0 1 1]; % your matrix
rowSum = sum(K, 2); % compute the sum
K_norm = K./repmat(rowSum, 1, size(K, 2));
```

`repmat` here builds a matrix with the same dimensions as `K` but with each column being the sum of rows of `K`.

Answer (score 0):

```
K=[0 0 1
0 2 1
0 1 1 ];
L = sum(K,2) ;
iwant = bsxfun(@rdivide,K,L)  ;
```

Comment: Again, please elaborate on the answer to give an explanation, and don't post double answers, instead just extend one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in two lines; first calculate the sum and then use `repmat` to make a matrix the same size as `K` and divide elementwise

```
L = sum(K,2);
iwant = K./repmat(L,1,size(K,2));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
K=[0 0 1
0 2 1
0 1 1 ];
L = sum(K,2) ;
iwant = zeros(size(K)) ;
for i = 1:size(K,1)
    iwant(i,:) = K(i,:)/L(i) ;
end
```

Comment: Did you try this code? You'll want element-wise operations at least. Besides, please elaborate on this answer and give a proper explanation what this code does and why it solves the OP's problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!